# getOrElse Scala Play JSON Payload

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am trying to not only clean this code up, but it is breaking when the `request.body isEmpty`, which defeats the purpose of this code segment.  I have been referring to Play's documentation to implement `getOrElse`, but I'm having a hard time trying to see how I can turn my code segment into what they've provided.  Here is the method:

```
  override def createWOTC(clientID: Int) =
Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>
  val partnerID = {
    if ((request.body \ "partner_id").as[String].isEmpty) "jobapp"
    else (request.body \ "partner_id").as[String]
  }
  val partnerAuth = {
    if ((request.body \ "partner_auth").as[String].isEmpty) "(snip)"
    else (request.body \ "partner_auth").as[String]
  }
  val handshakeURL = {
    if ((request.body \ "handshake_url").as[String].isEmpty) "(snip)"
    else (request.body \ "handshake_url").as[String]
  }
    ...


  wotcService.createWOTC(clientID, (request.body \ "company").as[String], (request.body \ "auth").as[String],
    partnerID, partnerAuth, handshakeURL, eligibilityURL, hireURL, pdfURL)
  NoContent
}
```

Comment: Try e.g. `val partnerID = (request.body \ "partner_id).as[String].getOrElse("jobapp")` instead of the first `if`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think `getOrElse` works here since `(request.body \ "partner_id").as[String]` returns a `String`.  I have tried that and `getOrElse symbol can not be resolved.`

Comment: You could try wrapping it with an `Option`.

Comment: It's probably not empty is null? You also could use wrap the `...as[String]` with a `Try` and call a `getOrElse` on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val partnerAuth = (request.body \ "partner_auth").asOpt[String].getOrElse("SxtWJbboccljiaii")
```

Comment: `asOpt` will return it as an Option then, I assume?  I was going to test it as `.as[Option[String]]]`, but that sounds like it does the same thing but probably cleaner?

Comment: yes exactly. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson#Using-JsValue.as/asOpt